# Can I user Enums inside my Razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Enum:

```
namespace Storage.Constants.References { 
    public enum RoleType {
        Guest = 1,
        User = 2,
        Admin = 3,
        Super = 4
    } 
}
```

The following viewmodel:

```
public class   BaseViewModel
{
    public int Role { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I have the following. Note that the Enum is recognized by the code.

```
@if (Model.Role >= RoleType.Admin) {
   xx
}
```

My code fails at runtime with the following message:

error CS0019: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Storage.Constants.References.RoleType'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options. cast RoleType.Admin to an int as RoleType.Admin is an Enum type.

```
@if (Model.Role >= (int)RoleType.Admin) { 
   xx 
}
```

Or make the property in BaseViewModel an enum, so no need for conversion:

```
public class   BaseViewModel
{
    public RoleType Role { get; set; }
}
@if (Model.Role >= RoleType.Admin) { 
   xx 
}
```

Comment: @Valamas And wouldn't pointing that I used == instead of >= suffice? That wasn't the reason for the downvote. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if (Model.Role >= (int)RoleType.Admin) { 
   xx 
}
```

Comment: You think I down voted you? Lol. Thanks for the down vote btw

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it that way, you need to convert RoleType.Admin to an int when comparing.

Comment: +1 From me, but it was someone else. He had only 1 down vote in profile, when both of as get -1.